# Can this JS syntax be mimicked in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, syntax

So I write a lot of JS and I'm a fan of *this* feature of the syntax. I'm not sure what *this* would be called, but below is an example.

```
object.function1().function2().function3()
```

I'm aware JS can do this because everything is treated as a first class object. But I was wondering if this is possible in C++? also what would a short example of that be?

Comment: Yup. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining.

Comment: You can do this if all function* return the reference of correct object in C++.

Comment: wow, that was a lot more obvious then I thought. 
@Fred thanks for the link

Comment: Your comment that 'JS can do this because everything is treated as a first class object' is not correct. Javascript's functional nature has nothing whatsoever to do with enabling method chaining (although it is the reason you can do `object.function('what')('the')('heck')` - in which `object.function()` returns a function to which you pass 'the' which in turn returns a function to which you pass 'heck', but I would never want to maintain that code!) I only point it out as the confusion might cause you some sort of subtle problem down the road.

Comment: i meant that I don't have to explicitly write the return of the chained JS methods to be the type of the object i want to run the next method of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, `this` is a pointer to the instance; you have to dereference it in order to return the instance:

```
return *this;
```

And if you want to avoid a copy so you can mutate the same object, you would return a reference. Here's an example:

```
struct X
{
    X& f() { std::cout << ++x << std::endl; return *this; }                    /*
    ^^                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                      */
private:
    int x = 0;
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.f().f().f(); // 1 2 3
}
```

Comment: good point about returning a reference, otherwise it will return a new copy of X, calling the default copy constructor.

Comment: So I want to use this so I can create a chain like **object.set().thisVaraible();**

I have my function setup like
    **class& set() {return *this; }**
and this does in fact just create a copy. Any thoughts as to how I might be using this wrong?

Comment: @MatUtter `set()` is **not** returning a copy in that code. Maybe you should post another question with more detail so you can get a comprehensive answer. :)

Comment: Actually there was no problem with it, I was just misinterpreting another weird glitch. Thank you a lot though its exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this:

```
class A{
public:
    A& foo(){ return *this; };
    A& bar() { return *this; };
};
```

and then

```
A a;
a.foo().bar();
```